# how to use scanf to scan double and char at the same time into a double array in C

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I have a project to do which asks me to record the address of two vectors into a double array according to user's input. However. For example, if user writes

> ```
> 3  
> 1 2 3  
> 3 4 5
> ```

it means that the vectors are 3 dimensional and the two vectors are `(1,2,3)(3,4,5)`. If user writes,

> ```
> 2  
> 1 2  
> 2 3
> ```

it means that the vectors are 2 dimensional and the two vectors are `(1,2)(2,3)`. I need to record the coordinates of these two vectors into two double arrays x, and y. How can I read the coordinates into these two arrays using scanf? (I don't know if the user writes in the correct format, it's possible for them to write letter or other symbol at the place where they are supposed to just write number. If they write chars other than number, i need to return -1.)

my code so far is

```
double x[100];  
char c;   
c = getchar();  
do {  
scanf("%lf",x)}  
while (c!= '\n');
```

Comment: You can't detect and recover from bad user input with `scanf`. Consider using `fgets` instead.

Comment: as I was previously suggesting you should tokenize params splitting whole lines into token with `strtok()` and covert them into float trough `atof()`.
As suggested from **melpomene** use `gets()` from `stdin`.

Comment: But I'm required to use scanf for this problem. Is it possible to store everything (double and char)into the array first and then check if the element in the array is numeric?

Comment: you cannot save double and char into a double array... maybe if you define an array of strings...

Comment: Why are you required to use `scanf` ? Is it homework ?

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use strtok() first.

Comment: Yes, it is a homework requirement.

Comment: forgive me I just checked `scanf()` docs and in case of format errors it return a negative value... then you can detect invalid inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, here is a code that should solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NB_VECTORS 2 //Increase if you have more than 2 vectors

int* readVector(int size) {
    // Allocation fits the size
    int* vector = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
   //While the vector are the same size it works
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (scanf("%d", vector+i) != 1)
             return null; //bad input
    return vector;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);

    //Each line is vectorized inside vectors[i]
    int* vectors[NB_VECTORS];#
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_VECTORS; i++)
        vectors[i] = readVector(size);

    return 0;
}
```

[EDIT]
returns the number of items it has filled -> cf http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: just a quick question, what's the " int size" in the "int* readVector(int size)" ?

Comment: is it the size of the array?

Comment: Yes, it is the size of the array

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is not a good function for parsing user input. It accepts `2.1sdsa2` as a float with the value `2.1` and it accepts `2.1sdsa2` as an int with value `2`. The `scanf` should only be used when you know that the input is valid.

If you are required to use `scanf`, you can scan into a string and then write your own parse to check that the input is valid.

A simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s[10];
  while (1 == scanf("%s", s))
  {
     printf("%s\n", s);
     if (strcmp(s, "s") == 0) break;
  }
  return(0);
}
```

The program continues until the input is `s`

Example of output:

```
1 2.0 2.6
1
2.0
2.6
2a 4567 2.a23
2a
4567
2.a23
s
s
```

Notice that `scanf` returns when it sees a space. So the input `1 2 3` will be 3 loops (aka 3 substrings returned).

So instead of just printing, you could put your parser inside the `while`:

```
  while (1 == scanf("%s", s))
  {
      // Parse the string s and add value to array
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you simply need something like this (simplistic, minimal, no error checking example):

```
int main()
{
  int x[3], y[3];

  int dimension;
  scanf("%d", &dimension);

  if (dimension == 3)
  {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x[0], &x[1], &x[2]);
    scanf("%d %d %d", &y[0], &y[1], &y[2]);
  }
  else if (dimension == 2)
  {
    scanf("%d %d", &x[0], &x[1]);
    scanf("%d %d", &y[0], &y[1]);
  }

  ...
  return 0;
}
```